# How to create multi ARRAY with PHP

Tags: php

I have:

```
$title1 = "aaa1";
$body1 = "bbb1";
$author1 = "ccc1";

$title2 = "aaa2";
$body2 = "bbb2";
$author2 = "ccc2";

$title3 = "aaa3";
$body3 = "bbb3";
$author3 = "ccc3";
```

How can i assign these variables to array? Next i would like make:

```
foreach($array as $a){
   $a[title] . $a['body']. $a['author'] . "<br />";
}
```

and this should show me:

```
aaa1bbb1ccc1
aaa2bbb2ccc2
aaa3bbb3ccc3
```

Comment: [So many people had the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+how+to+create+a+multidimensional+array)... don't think you could apply these answers to your case?

Comment: I voted to close the question as "not constructive". There is no specific  expertise needed to answers this question, one just has to be able to *read* the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (example 15 to be precise). SO is not the right place to *learn* a language. That's what tutorials and documentation are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array(    
     0 => array('title' => 'aaa1', 'body => 'bbb1','author' => 'ccc1'),    
     1 => array('title' => 'aaa2', 'body => 'bbb2','author' => 'ccc2'),    
     2 => array('title' => 'aaa3', 'body => 'bbb3','author' => 'ccc3')
);
```

or use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to create the array

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[] = array("title" => "aaa1", "body" => "bbbb1");
$array[] = array("title" => "aaa2", "body" => "bbbb2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just create an array in an array.

```
<?php
$array = array(
        array('title' => 'aaa1', 'body' => 'bbb1', 'author' => 'ccc1'),
        array('title' => 'aaa2', 'body' => 'bbb2', 'author' => 'ccc2'),
        array('title' => 'aaa3', 'body' => 'bbb3', 'author' => 'ccc3'),
    );
```

Just read the PHP documentation about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php .

Answer (score 0):

basically

> An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.

```
array(
key  => value,
key2 => value2,
key3 => value3,
...
```

)

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

MORE INFO http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You would do like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
        array('title' => 'aaa1', 'body' => 'bbb1', 'author' => 'ccc1'),
        array('title' => 'aaa2', 'body' => 'bbb2', 'author' => 'ccc2'),
        array('title' => 'aaa3', 'body' => 'bbb3', 'author' => 'ccc3'),
    );
?>
```

and then you would print the way you want like this:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $item) {
    print($item['title'].$item['body'].$item['author']."<br>");
}
?>
```